# How to repeat Left Most rows for a group in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have an SSRS Report which is having groups. I need left most rows to be repeated in the tablix for the group.

Example:

Original Report is like below

```
Country    Region    Category    Total
------------------------------------------
                    Group Total    1000 
                    Product 1      200 
USA        NORTH    Product 2      300
                    Product 3      300
                    Product 4      200
------------------------------------------
                    Group Total    500
USA        SOUTH    Product 1      200
                    Product 2      300
------------------------------------------
```

But I want the report to be modified to be like below.

```
Country    Region    Category    Total
------------------------------------------
USA        NORTH    Group Total    1000 
USA        NORTH    Product 1      200 
USA        NORTH    Product 2      300
USA        NORTH    Product 3      300
USA        NORTH    Product 4      200
------------------------------------------
USA        SOUTH    Group Total    500
USA        SOUTH    Product 1      200
USA        SOUTH    Product 2      300
------------------------------------------
```

We have a row level Group on CATEGORY column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Delete existing Country and Region columns and groups
2. In your Category group make sure you also include Country and Region
3. In Category Group Sorting, sort By Country, Region, Category
4. At the Product row level add columns for Country and Region
5. In the Category Group Header also add Country and Region
6. Add Country and Region Titles

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the Group Column "Category" and Add New Column to the Left.
2. Copy the Column "Region" in Header, Copy the "Region Data Element" for both the "Group Total", "Product".
3. Delete Old "Region" Column. Add New column to the left of the New "Region" Column and copy the "Country"
4. Do the same for all the previous columns.